# Test of hypothesis

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

[image]

Can you help for solving this question.What ı will use to solve this problem.I try to do something but ı thınk not correct.ı have an exam please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

above 2 answer is wrong!, since that is identical trial which is only repeated measure from 7 times shoot with the same treatment, hence why both of u used $x^2$ test and $F$ test?

Hint: Remember repeated measure from 7 times shoot with the same treatment is an identical, so that we can assume and u can check the normality, which is normally independent. ($iid$) hence you should used $t$-test for 1 independent sample.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma_1^{2}=30$ meters $=$ Population variance of "Hawk" type army rockets.

$\sigma^{2}=$ Population variance of "Owl" type army rockets.

$n=7$

Calculating the sample standard deviation of the "Owl" rocket tests, we get

$S=\sqrt\frac{\Sigma (x-\overline{x})^2}{n-1}=\sqrt\frac{6^2+5^2+3^2+4^2+3^2+6^2+5^2}{7-1}=\sqrt{26}$

$H_0:\sigma^{2}=30$

$H_1:\sigma^{2}<30$

Now we calculate chi squared value $\chi^2=\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma_1^{2}}=5.2$

And we have $\chi_{critical}^2\approx12.592$ at $\nu=n-1=6$ and $\alpha=0.05$

Since $\chi^2<\chi_{critical}^2$ we fail to reject $H_0$ and hence there is no strong evidence to conclude that "Owl" rockets are more accurate than "Hawk" rockets.

Comment: Are you sure that you calculate s with correct way because ı found s=1.12

Comment: The distances given in the tests are off target. We have target distance as the mean, i.e., $138$ meters and say the first test was off the target by $6$ meters. This is equivalent to $x-\overline{x}=\pm6$

Comment: I dont understand why we dont have a mean is 4.6 @user74820

Comment: 4.6 as mean is incorrect. What you are asserting is that the rocket "Owl" just fired 6,5,3,4,3,5,6 meters away in the test. While the question clearly says that these distances are off target distances.

Comment: Suppose the target was 100 meters away and the rocket "Owl" hit 6 meters away from the target. The distance the "Owl" rocket covered is $100\pm6$ meters. And therefore by this analogy, we infer that $x-\overline{x}=\pm6$.

Comment: My english is not so good so ı am confused :) 100-6=94 ? @user74820

Comment: Okey ı try to understand thank you @user74820

Comment: The way you did this: $S=\sqrt\frac{\Sigma (x-\overline{x})^2}{n-1}=\sqrt\frac{\Sigma (x-4.6)^2}{7-1}\approx1.12$

The way the question asked: $S=\sqrt\frac{\Sigma (x-\overline{x})^2}{n-1}=\sqrt\frac{6^2+5^2+3^2+4^2+3^2+6^2+5^2}{7-1}=\sqrt{26}$

Comment: Yes ı did like this :) this is the first time ı saw such ı guestion ı should be careful about this @user74820

Comment: Your way of analyzing this was that "Owl" travelled $6,5,3,4,3,5,6$ meters in $7$ tests. Hence the mean is $\frac{6+5+3+4+3+5+6}{7}\approx4.57$. However the mean IS the target distance and the test distances given in the question are deviation from the target.

Comment: I understand thanks for helping @user74820